# KendoUI - grid - template not getting data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have problem with KenfoUI grid. From server side I'm sending JSON data:

```
{
"data": [{
    "process": {
        "id": "myProcess2:1:1206",
            "description": null,
            "name": "My process 2",
            "version": 1
    },
        "id": 42066,
        "description": "unisono-rest-evenem",
        "type": {
        "id": 2,
            "translation": "Faktura sprzedażowa",
            "name": "salesInvoice"
    },
        "triger": {
        "id": 42048,
            "name": "Document recognized trigger",
            "code": "ocrEndTrigger",
            "type": "DOCUMENT_RECOGNIZED"
    }
}, {
    "process": {
        "id": "myProcess2:1:1206",
            "description": null,
            "name": "My process 2",
            "version": 1
    },
        "id": 42067,
        "description": "6756757",
        "type": {
        "id": 5,
            "translation": "Słownik stawek VAT",
            "name": "dictVatRates"
    },
        "triger": {
        "id": 42048,
            "name": "Document recognized trigger",
            "code": "ocrEndTrigger",
            "type": "DOCUMENT_RECOGNIZED"
    }
}, {
    "process": {
        "id": "myProcess2:1:1206",
            "description": null,
            "name": "My process 2",
            "version": 1
    },
        "id": 42068,
        "description": "56546546",
        "type": {
        "id": 1,
            "translation": "Faktura",
            "name": "invoice"
    },
        "triger": {
        "id": 42047,
            "name": "New document trigger",
            "code": "createDocument",
            "type": "CREATE_DOCUMENT"
    }
}, {
    "process": {
        "id": "myProcess2:1:1206",
            "description": null,
            "name": "My process 2",
            "version": 1
    },
        "id": 42069,
        "description": "swswsws",
        "type": {
        "id": 5,
            "translation": "Słownik stawek VAT",
            "name": "dictVatRates"
    },
        "triger": {
        "id": 42047,
            "name": "New document trigger",
            "code": "createDocument",
            "type": "CREATE_DOCUMENT"
    }
}],
    "total": 4
}
```

and I defined columns in gird like:

```
    columns: [{
    field: "process",
    title: "Nazwa procesu",
    editor: staticEditors.processEditor,
        "template": function (data) {
        if (data.process != null && data.process != undefined) {
            return "<span class='gridText' title='" + data.process.name + "'>" + data.process.name + "</span>"
        } else {
            return "<span></span>"
        }
    }
}, {
    field: "type",
    title: "Typ dokumentu",
    editor: $scope.typeEditor,
        "template": function (data) {
        if (data.type != null && data.type != undefined) {
            return "<span class='gridText' title='" + data.type.translation + "'>" + data.type.translation + "</span>"
        } else {
            return "<span></span>"
        }
    }
}, {
    field: "triger",
    title: "Wyzwalacz",
    editor: staticEditors.triggerEditor,
        "template": function (data) {
        if (data.triger != null && data.triger != undefined) {
            return "<span class='gridText' title='" + data.triger.name + "'>" + data.triger.name + "</span>"
        } else {
            return "<span></span>"
        }
    }
}, {
    field: "description",
    title: "Description",
        "template": function (data) {
        if (data.description != null && data.description != undefined) {
            return "<span class='gridText' title='" + data.description + "'>" + data.description + "</span>"
        } else {
            return "<span></span>"
        }
    }
}
```

There is a problem in template function because data object doesn't have all data. I noticed that has problem with nested data (field like type, trigger, process has null or string ("[object Object]") values.)

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Seems to work fine if I copy/paste your columns and data: http://dojo.telerik.com/EKuLi

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem.
I defined schema.model.field as numer(string). When I removed that, everything work's fine.

Answer (score -1):

Template is not string in column,

try like this,

```
{
    field: "triger",
    title: "Wyzwalacz",
    editor: staticEditors.triggerEditor,
    template: function (data) {
        if (data.triger != null && data.triger != undefined) {
            return "<span class='gridText' title='" + data.triger.name + "'>" + data.triger.name + "</span>"
    } else {
        return "<span></span>"
    }
}
```

Remove `"template"` and do this `template` i think that solved your problem.

Comment: it dosn't help. I think there is no difference between this two posibilities. The problem is that, template function is working, whole data is soming from server (I checked it in schema.parse function) but in data object (in template function) application not see nested object.

Comment: `template` and `"template"` are the same in JavaScript. Quotes around the property name will make no difference.